# Orthogonal functions in differential equations

Tags: inner-products

A well-known theorem of elementary geometry states that the sum of the squares of the sides of a parallelogram equals the sum of the squares of its diagonals. Prove that this so-called para elogram law is true for the norm in R:

First I was not sure whether the following is correct:

$||f-g||^2=(f,f)-2(f,g)+(g,g)$

If it is then:

$2||f||^2+2||g||^2=||f+g||^2+||f-g||^2$

I will first show from RHS -> LHS

$||f+g||^2+||f-g||^2$

$=(f+g,f+g)+(f-g,f-g)$

$=(f,f)+2(f,g)+(g,g)+(f,f)-2(f,g)+(g,g)$

$=2(f,f)+2(g,g)$

$=2||f||^2+2||g||^2$

Now from LHS -> RHS

$2||f||^2+2||g||^2$

$=2(f,f)+2(g,g)$

$=(f,f)+(f,f)+(g,g)+(g,g)+0$

$=(f,f)+(f,f)+(g,g)+(g,g)+2(f,g)-2(f,g)$

$=(f,f)+2(f,g)+(g,g)+(f,f)-2(f,g)+(g,g)$

$=(f+g,f+g)+(f-g,f-g)$

$=||f+g||^2+||f-g||^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add $0$ to the last line, the write that $0$ as $2(f,g)-2(f,g)$, then use those to complete the squares. And your first formula is correct.

Comment: Thank you, does that look right?